# CABasicAnimation lags (iOS5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cabasicanimation

i got some simple animation that works perfect on iOS 6, but on iOS5 its lagging and often freezes screen without any reason

i need help really, because i dont have any ideas what could be wrong here. By the way i tried to turn off each of the animations, and looks like the problem is in "transform" animation

here is the code:

```
-(void)drawDotAtPointAnimated:(CGPoint)p withRadius:(CGFloat)radius andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
CGRect circleFrame = CGRectMake(p.x - radius*self.scale, p.y - radius*self.scale, radius*2*self.scale, radius*2*self.scale);
CGPoint circleAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

NSLog(@"animating dot with x = %f and y = %f", p.x, p.y);
NSLog(@"=====mid x = %f, mid y = %f", CGRectGetMidX(circleFrame), CGRectGetMidY(circleFrame));
NSLog(@"=====max x = %f, max y = %f", CGRectGetMaxX(circleFrame), CGRectGetMaxY(circleFrame));

self.shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, circleFrame.size.width, circleFrame.size.height)];
self.shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
self.shapeLayer.anchorPoint = circleAnchor;
self.shapeLayer.frame = circleFrame;
self.shapeLayer.fillColor = color.CGColor;

[self.layer addSublayer:self.shapeLayer];

CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0, 0.0, 0)];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(4.0, 4.0, 1.0)];
if(self.mode == GameModeOffline) {
    animation.repeatCount = OFFLINE_GAME_DOT_ANIMATION_REPEAT_COUNT;
} else {
    animation.repeatCount = ONLINE_GAME_DOT_ANIMATION_REPEAT_COUNT;
}
animation.duration = 1;
animation.delegate = self;
[self.shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
if(self.mode == GameModeOffline) {
    fadeAnim.repeatCount = OFFLINE_GAME_DOT_ANIMATION_REPEAT_COUNT;
} else {
    fadeAnim.repeatCount = ONLINE_GAME_DOT_ANIMATION_REPEAT_COUNT;
}
[self.shapeLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];

self.shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(4.0, 4.0, 1);
self.shapeLayer.opacity = 0.0;
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Scale by zero at start? Don't you want to scale by {1, 1, 1} ? (ie. identity transform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale by zero at start? Don't you want to scale by {1, 1, 1} ? (ie. identity transform)

(It seems this has simply solved the problem, so I'm posting my comment as an answer).

Comment: but im still surprising that it works perfectly on iOS6 even with zero scale